# Get a desired percentage of censored observations in a simulation of Cox PH Model

Tags: r, optimization, censoring, cox-model

This question comes from:

[How to simulate a Cox proportional hazards model with change point and code it in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64433/how-to-simulate-a-cox-proportional-hazards-model-with-change-point-and-code-it-i) (See answer)

I want to generate a censoring variable $C=Exponential(\theta)$ that create a desired percentage of censorship on $Y$, like 33%, 55%, etc, by choosing an appropriate value for $\theta$.

In order to include this censoring variable in the code I did for the previous question, I added this to the dataframe generator:

```
cen <- rexp(n,theta) # Censoring variable.

ycen <- pmin(Y, cen) # Censoring effect.
di <- as.numeric(Y <= cen)
```

...

```
if (surv.df) data.frame(Y,X,ycen,di) else cbind(Y,X,ycen,di)
```

To do something like this (in the context of the aforementioned simulation):

```
coxph(Surv(ycen, di)~X)
```

Which $\theta$ value should I choose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if this answers your question but please find below some R code which follows Bender et al. (2005). They describe an approach to simulate a Cox PH regression model with given properties like the proportion of censored events (see line "`dat <- data.frame(T = T, X, event = rbinom(n, 1, 0.30))`", i.e. 70% of all events are censored).

**Reference**

Bender, Ralf, Thomas Augustin, und Maria Blettner. 2005. Generating survival times to simulate Cox proportional hazards models. Statistics in Medicine 24: 1713–1723.

```
##' Generate survival data with $p$ (correlated) predictors
##'
##' 
##'
##' @title Generate survival data
##' @param n Sample size
##' @param beta Vector of coefficients
##' @param r Correlation between predictors
##' @param id.iter 
##' @param id.study
##' @return matrix with identification variables id.iter and id.study,
##'         T (survival time), event (0: censored),
##'         predictors X1 to X$p$
##' @author Bernd Weiss
##' @references Bender et al. (2005)
genSurvData <- function(n = 100000,
                        beta = c(0.8, 2.2, -0.5, 1.1, -1.4),
                        r = 0.1,
                        id.iter = NA,
                        id.study = NA){

    ## Scale parameter (the smaller lambda, the greater becomes T)
    lambda <- 0.000001#1.7

    ## Shape parameter
    nue <- 8.9#9.4

    ## Sample size
    n <- n

    ## Number of predictors
    p <- length(beta)

    ## Generate column vector of coefficients
    beta <- matrix(beta, ncol = 1)

    ## Generate correlated covariate vectors using a multivariate normal
    ## distribution with X ~ N(mu, S) and a given correlation matrix R, with:
    ## R: A p x p correlation matrix
    ## mu: Vector of means
    ## SD: Vector of standard deviations
    ## S: Variance-covariance matrix
    R <- matrix(c(rep(r, p^2)), ncol = p)
    diag(R) <- 1
    R
    mu <- rep(0, p)
    SD <- rep(1, p)
    S <- R * (SD %*% t(SD))
    X <- mvrnorm(n, mu, S)
    cov(X)
    cor(X)
    sqrt(diag(cov(X)))

    ## Calculate survival times
    T <- (-log(runif(n)) / (lambda * exp(X %*% beta)))^(1/nue)

    ## 30% (0.30) of all marriages are getting divorced, i.e. 70% of all
    ## observations are censored ("event = rbinom(n, 1, 0.30)")
    dat <- data.frame(T = T, X, event = rbinom(n, 1, 0.30))
    ## Also, all T's > 30 yrs are by definition censored and T is set to 30 yrs
    dat$event <- ifelse(dat$T >= 30, 0, dat$event)
        dat$T <- ifelse(dat$T >= 30, 30, dat$T)

    dat$id.iter <- id.iter
    dat$id.study <- id.study

    ## Reorder data frame: T, event, covariates
    tmp.names <- names(dat)
    dat <- dat[, c("id.iter", "id.study", "T", "event", tmp.names[grep("X", tmp.names)])]

    ## Returning a matrix speeds-up things a lot... lesson learned.
    dat <- as.matrix(dat)
    return(dat)
}


library(survival)
library(MASS)

dat <- genSurvData(n = 1000)
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)

survfit(Surv(time = T, event = event) ~ 1, data = dat)

coxph(Surv(time = T, event = event) ~ X1 + X2 + X3 +X4 +X5, data = dat)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll adapt the code to my simulation study in order to get some results.